# do you recommend wpf for POS

Tags: wpf

is wpf (technology) based interface is good for Point of Sale application?

my fears are wpf is immature, slow, eat memory too much, processor clocks in short required good machines which i think POS terminal doesn't has...

plus point i believe are

cool and powerful interface, good for win 7 and touch screen based but i dont' know how good machines/terminals normally people get for POS

any suggestion.. either winforms or wpf for POS app?

Comment: how come? can you please shed some light on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Martinho Fernandes that WPF shouldn't be considered immature. That said, as with all things, it depends...

The first step in creating any architecture is understanding your requirements and constraints. In this case it sounds like you need to learn more about the hardware and run-time enviroments.

Most importantly: Will machines have .NET 3.5 installed?

In my experience, WPF doesn't use more hardware resources than Windows Forms for the same tasks. Sure, WPF can do all sorts of hardware-intensive things with the graphics card that would be (close to) impossiblw with Windows Forms, but *you don't have to use these capabilities* just because they are there.

I would be suprised if we see more development of Windows Forms from Microsoft. WPF and Silverlight is the future for rich clients, so unless you have *very compelling* reasons to choose Windows Forms, WPF/Silverlight is the way to go.

Comment: I agree what you said and thanks for sharing your knowledge. 

Do you know if i can run my app in win 2k and xp in same way as i can run in vista and win7? means its look and feel remain same?

what hardware (graphics memory, memory and processor) is recommended for simple WPF based Point of sale application? any recommendations? or least requirement to get benefit of WPF...

i m using wpf for few days and feeling it slower than winforms thats why getting concious about its performance.

Comment: The minimum support OS version for WPF is XP SP2, so you can't run it on Windows 2000. This post summarizes the hardware requirements for WPF (there are none per se) pretty well: http://www.fernicola.org/loquitor/index.php?/archives/21-guid.html